# Removing Windows library dependencies

Tags: c++, multithreading, std, mutex, portability

I have a couple of classes here that I would like to remove window library dependencies for portability reasons. One for blocking processes and the other for blocking threads. Both of these classes compile & runs fine as is...  As for the `BlockProcess` class it is currently using a `HANDLE` for a mutex and using function calls such as: {`CreateMutex()`, `CloseHandle()` & `GetLastError()`}. As for the `BlockThread` class it uses a pointer to a `CRITICAL_SECTION` calling functions such as: {`EnterCricticalSection()` & `LeaveCriticalSection()`}.

What I would like to know is there an equivalent way to do this using something from the `std` library such as `std::mutex`, `std::thread` etc. that will provide the same functionality. I would like to remove the need to have `#include<windows.h>` & possibly `#include<process.h>`.

Here are my existing classes:

---

> *`BlockProcess.h`*

```
#ifndef BLOCK_PROCESS_H
#define BLOCK_PROCESS_H

#include <Windows.h>
#include <process.h>
#include <string>

namespace demo {

class BlockProcess final {
private:
    HANDLE hMutex_;
public:
    explicit BlockProcess( const std::string& strName );
    ~BlockProcess();

    bool isBlocked() const;

    BlockProcess( const BlockProcess& c ) = delete;
    BlockProcess& operator=( const BlockProcess& c ) = delete;
};

} // namespace demo

#endif // !BLOCK_PROCESS_H
```

> *`BlockProcess.cpp`*

```
#include "BlockProcess.h"

namespace demo {

BlockProcess::BlockProcess( const std::string& strName ) {
    hMutex_ = CreateMutex( nullptr, FALSE, strName.c_str() );
} 

BlockProcess::~BlockProcess() {
    CloseHandle( hMutex_ );
}

bool BlockProcess::isBlocked() const {
    return (hMutex_ == nullptr || GetLastError() == ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS);
}
```

---

> *`BlockThread.h`*

```
#ifndef BLOCK_THREAD_H
#define BLOCK_THREAD_H

#include <Windows.h>

namespace demo { 

class BlockThread final {
private:
    CRITICAL_SECTION* pCriticalSection_;

public:
    explicit BlockThread( CRITICAL_SECTION& criticalSection );
    ~BlockThread();

    BlockThread( const BlockThread& c ) = delete;
    BlockThread& operator=( const BlockThread& c ) = delete;
}; 

} // namespace demo

#endif // !BLOCK_THREAD_H


} // namespace demo
```

> *`BlockThread.cpp`*

```
#include "BlockThread.h"

namespace demo { 

BlockThread::BlockThread( CRITICAL_SECTION& criticalSection ) {
    pCriticalSection_ = &criticalSection;
    EnterCriticalSection( pCriticalSection_ );
} 

BlockThread::~BlockThread() {
    LeaveCriticalSection( pCriticalSection_ );
}

} // namespace demo
```

---

**Edit**

If you need an example of how these classes are used feel free to leave a comment.

Comment: `CreateMutex` creates a cross-process mutex there is currently nothing in the standard library with regard to processes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `BlockThread` is essentially `std::lock_guard` (to be used over an `std::mutex` instead of `CRITICAL_SECTION`). It can be trivially replaced with standard library code.

As for `BlockProcess` (creation of a cross-process synchronization object), there's no standard equivalent.

Comment: `#include <thread> #include <mutex> #include <atomic>` are all useful includes for cross platform threading.

Comment: Okay I think that kind of makes sense now. For blocking threads there is a similar mechanism in the library, but as for `processes` because they are `machine - os` dependent there is no `standard` way as they are platform specific.

Comment: To block a processes, you'll need to use `#include <condition_variable> std::condition_variable` in combination with you mutex to make a process wait.

Comment: So with the current `BlockProcess` class I'm still inclined to have to `#include<Windows.h>` for declaring a `HANDLE` and using `CreateMutex()` and `CloseHandle()`...

Comment: All you need is `std::mutex locker;` to create a mutex. Here is a good example.
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/condition_variable/condition_variable/wait/

Comment: @FrancisCugler: well, it's not written in the stone - even threads required platform specific code before C++11, but eventually they standardized a common interface. But yes, as for now the C++ standard provides no facility to manage processes.

Comment: @aj.toulan The functionality with the `BlockProcess` class here is that the `string` it takes is the name of the currently running executable. If you pass that string to the constructor of this class and then in an `if statement` you call to check to see if `isBlocked()` returns true or not from there if the executable is already running in memory, I typically will throw an exception. Its to prevent multiple running occurrences of the same application.

Comment: @aj.toulan: the classes you are citing can be used for cross thread synchronization, not cross process.

Comment: @MatteoItalia The 2 classes are `Independent` of each other. The one for `BlockProcess` is used to prevent multiple simultaneously running instances of the same executable. For the `BlockThread` it is to help with `synchronization` across multiple threads.

Comment: @FrancisCugler: yes, I'm aware of that, in facts as I wrote in my answer you can replace `BlockThread` but not `BlockProcess`. I was just trying to explain it to aj.toulan.

Comment: @MatteoItalia Ah okay, my apologies about the confusion; I overlooked the fact that you directed the comment towards another user...

Comment: Oh, you're right! I'm sorry, I jumped the gun! I've done more C++ on windows but more threading C++ coding on unix. I should have read more carefully.

Comment: So typically with `Threading` you can remove platform specific code, but as for `Processes` your left at the mercy of the OS...

Answer (score 2):

boost interprocess does offer cross-platform inter-process synchronization objects (akin to the inter-thread objects of the standard library). But the standard library types are purely in-process.

Comment: That is nice to know about `boost`. I don't mind using boost however in this current project it is `boost` free...